# deleting Ant dirset using regex

Tags: ant, delete-file

I am trying to delete a set of directories using a regex expression, but not having much luck at all, can anyone take a look at the target please:

```
    <delete failonerror="true" includeemptydirs="true">
        <dirset dir="C:\Users\martin\Desktop\testing" includes="*">
            <containsregexp expression="[0-9]*-0" />
        </dirset>
     </delete>
```

It just won't delete the files, I want it to match the folder [0-9]*-0 and if it matches it, to delete it

Comment: <dirset dir="C:\Users\martin\Desktop\testing">
  <patternset>
    <include name="[0-9]*-0"/>
     </patternset>
</dirset>

Comment: no luck unfortunately

Comment: what's the err you got?

Comment: no error, the files just haven't been deleted

Answer (score 0):

The delete task will delete an individual directory but not ones from a dirset.

I have the following directory structure:

```html
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\012345-0
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\012345-1
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\987565-0
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\012345-0\sometext.txt
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\012345-0\subdir1
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\012345-0\subdir2
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\012345-0\subdir1\sometext.txt
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\012345-0\subdir2\sometext.txt
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\012345-1\sometext.txt
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\012345-1\subdir1
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\012345-1\subdir2
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\012345-1\subdir1\sometext.txt
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\012345-1\subdir2\sometext.txt
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\987565-0\sometext.txt
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\987565-0\subdir1
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\987565-0\subdir2
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\987565-0\subdir1\sometext.txt
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\987565-0\subdir2\sometext.txt
```

I created this ant target (ant 1.8.2)

```xml
   <target name="regexptest">
      <fileset dir="C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\" includes="**/**" id="regexp.todelete">
          <filename regex="[0-9]*-0" />
      </fileset>
      <!-- Which files are selected? -->
      <pathconvert pathsep="${line.separator}" property="prop.regexp.test" refid="regexp.todelete" />
      <echo message="Will delete:" />
      <echo message="${prop.regexp.test}" />
      <delete failonerror="true" includeemptydirs="true" verbose="true">
        <fileset refid="regexp.todelete" />
     </delete>
   </target>
```

The directory structure after the task had run:

```html
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\012345-1
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\012345-1\sometext.txt
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\012345-1\subdir1
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\012345-1\subdir2
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\012345-1\subdir1\sometext.txt
C:\dev\debug_investigations\purge_deployment\test\012345-1\subdir2\sometext.txt
```

It's more verbose than it needs to be for production, but I hope this helps future regex directory deleters!